# Issuing HTTP Get Request in Flexible Environment in App Engine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, go, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-go

I am using Flexible Environment in App engine I want to send HTTP Get request in my code.

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com/", nil)
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintf(w, "HTTP GET returned status %v", res.Status)
```

When I run app I get the following error:
**https://www.google.com/: not an App Engine context**

The above code works in Standard Environment and but it is not working in flexible environment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need URL Fetch in App Engine Flexible, you can simply issue the http request: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/migrating#url_fetch